# How can function to find Hamming Distance be accelerated for bigger datas in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, multiprocessing, hamming-distance

I have a potgreSQL data bank with more than 10,0000 entries and each entry has a bit array of size 10000. Is there any method to accelerate the Hamming Distance calculation of the bit arrays for the whole table. Thanks

i tried using different data types like bytea, text and numeric for saving bit array and for calculating hamming distance i tried XOR gate operations, text comparison and numeric addition respectively for each datatypes. But i could not optimize the function to make it super quick, currently it takes almost 2 sec for the operation. The target is 200 millisecond.

Comment: If I wanted this super fast, I would not use a RDBMS for this in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you could develop you function in [C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/xfunc-c.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibilities to have good performances for hamming distance because it's a recursive process with a high algorithmic complexity and a very high memory footprint.
[https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~brody/papers/random14-hamming-distance.pdf](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Ebrody/papers/random14-hamming-distance.pdf)

It is not accurate to use it in some big datasets like RDBMS.

Some other comparing technics exists and have a lower complexity withour recursive process and with a minimal footprint... They are not as accurate as the Hamming Distance, but can do a good job, as the one I wrote :

[See "inférence basique"](https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/sql/comparaisons-motifs/#LVI)

You can combine the two... First use inférence basique to reduce the set, second use hamming on some very few results...